# Include a record only if it has more than 20 related records

Tags: sql

This is the statement that I'm using:

```
SELECT
    country.code as "Country Code",
    country.name as Country,    
    count(countrycode) as "Number Of Cities"
FROM
    city,
    country
WHERE
    city.countrycode = country.code
GROUP BY country.code, country.name;
```

I need to select countries that have more than 20 cities. I will create a view for this query afterwards.

Comment: +1 for using `GROUP BY` correctly.

Comment: You don't need to group by country name. Country code should be enough as name will be unique for each code

Comment: Also please accept Kermit's answer if it has solved your problem

Answer (score 3):

Use the `HAVING` clause for aggregate functions:

```
...
GROUP BY country.code, country.name
HAVING COUNT(countrycode) > 20;
```

Comment: @user3508421 It may be helpful to future visitors if you updated your question and tagged it with the DBMS you're using (SQL Server, PostgreSQL, MySQL, etc.)